# How to change the postgresql.conf parameter on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

How to change the postgresql.conf parameter "max_connections" on Google Cloud SQL?

When I exceed 100 connections I get the error: "FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"

Comment: You're usually better off putting a connection pooler like pgbouncer in front. Surprised they don't do that automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally you would do it via CloudSQL flags API (or UI): https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags

However, `max_connections` is not a parameter we currently support. We (Postgres team in CloudSQL) are aware that low `max_connections` is a problem for some (many?) applications and will address issue in one of the next releases.

Please follow [issue 37271935](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37271935) on our public issue tracker for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Years later, it seems like it's supported now.

For the Terraform gang, you can update the parameter this way:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "main" {
  name             = "main-instance"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_14"
  region           = "us-central1"

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"

    database_flags {
      name  = "max_connections"
      value = 100
    }
  }
}
```

Note that at the time of writing the `db-f1-micro` default `max_connections` is 25, refs https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-m